# Which characters are in the next tier after the "God 4"?

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-2

I love playing this game but I am not a huge fan of archetypal teams like MSP, SSCC, etc.  I'm good at playing Cable, but who isn't?  I want to learn a team that might stand a chance of competing with the God 4 but might be more diverse or use a couple lesser-known characters.

If there were a hypothetical Marvel vs. Capcom 2 tournament where Magneto, Storm, Cable, and Sentinel were banned, what would the metagame look like?

Which characters are the best if these game-breaking ones are removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was at an MVC2 tournament a couple years ago at University Pinball in Philly that banned top-tier characters. This place is famous for having some of the best MVC2 players in the world.

Here are the top characters I saw *winning* after several hours of watching and playing:

- **Iron Man**: For sure. Easiest infinite combo outside of top-tier. Awesome character besides. Proton Cannon is the poor man's Hyper Beam, and quite easy to combo into.
- **Doctor Doom**: Of course. Awesome assist, flies, great range, overall great character.
- **Spiral**: My personal favorite. Spamming knives, teleport, good assist. Easy to abuse with skill.
- **Psylocke**: Highly abused assist, probably only decent otherwise.
- **Colossus**: Almost forgot about this guy. He can be a beast, and is very powerful. Great cleanup character used with his shoulder charge assist.

Some other honorable mentions:

- **Silver Samurai**: Apparently this guy is nasty if you know how to use him, which few people do. More of a skill character than a "top-tier", but has potential. Saw one guy who was really putting him to work.
- **Cammy**: I saw one guy in particular leading and cleaning up with Cammy. She has high priority in a lot of situations if you know how to use her apparently. I don't know if this would really belong on this list however, but I saw her win a lot of matches.
- **Captain Commando**: Solid character. Saw him in position 2 mostly.
- **Tron Bonne**: Valued assist character, saw a lot of her.

Juggernaut would have been on the list if the power-up glitch* wasn't banned.

Since this was a "fun" tournament, I suspect some of the choices weren't optimal, but these were the characters I saw winning the most out of about 6 machines and 50 or so hardcore MVC2 players.

<sub>* If Juggernaut Powers-up (DP+PP) and immediately tags out without attacking in any way, his Power-up damage remains permanent for the rest of the round</sub>